# apache cannot stop and always down in uniserver

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, codeigniter

I'm working with system that uses Apache uniserver and code framework is PHP Codeigniter. Somehow it is always down and gives the error below in log. Can anyone guide me on how to fix this?

> PHP Fatal error: session_set_save_handler(): Session handler's function table is corrupt in
>   C:\UniServerZ\ssl\portal\system\libraries\Session\Session.php on line 11
>
> [php7:error] [pid 5168:tid 1932] [client 175.139.156.154:52516] PHP Fatal error: Class CI_Session_database_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SessionHandlerInterface::&) in C:\UniServerZ\ssl\portal\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php on line 49,

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: CI_VERSION 3.0.0 and PHP 7.1.1@AbhishekMugal